# Diagonalizable subgroups of a connected linear algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected linear algebraic group
over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic 0.
Let $D\subset G$ be a closed diagonalizable subgroup of $G$
(a subgroup of multiplicative type).
Is it true that $D$ is contained  in some torus  $T\subset G$?

This is so for  $G=\mathrm{GL}_n$.
Is this true for any connected linear  $G$ (or any connected reductive $G$)?

I am stuck with this simple question...

**Edit.** The answer to the original question is NO, see Angelo's answer. 
However, is it true that any *cyclic* finite diagonalizable subgroup $C$ of $G$ 
is contained in some torus $T\subset G$?

Comment: For **the cyclic case**: If $D = \langle s \rangle$ is a cyclic
diagonalizable subgroup of a connected linear algebraic group $G$, then $s$ is a
semisimple element of $G$ (of finite order). In particular, $s$ and
hence $D$ is contained in a maximal torus of $G$. Indeed, by [Borel
LAG,11.10] $s$ is contained in a Borel subgroup of $G$, and then the claim
follows from the connected solvable case [Borel LAG,10.6].


Comment: The answer for cyclic finite diagonalizable groups is affirmative for connected reductive $G$; this is Lemma 7.1 in the Appendix of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.8161.pdf (where $\mu_n$ is written, but the initial reduction to algebraically closed ground field does not use that the cyclic group is split -- i.e., constant Cartier dual -- and so it gives the result in general).

Comment: @nfdc23, since we're in characteristic 0 and so everything is smooth, probably [@GeorgeMcNinch](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60781/diagonalizable-subgroups-of-a-connected-linear-algebraic-group#comment153414_60781)'s comment and [@JimHumphrey](http://mathoverflow.net/a/60801/2383)'s answer is an easier way to think about that, no?  (The reference's citation of Steinberg's connectedness theorem even in the smooth case is overkill.)

Comment: @LSpice: Probably.  Somewhat stubbornly I wanted to address arbitrary characteristic (it makes me happier), so I didn't think at all about methods specific to characteristic zero.  :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. For example, $\mathrm{PGL}_n$ contains a subgroup $G$ isomorphic to the product of two cyclic subgroups of order $n$, generated by the classes of the diagonal matrix whose entries are the powers of a fixed primitive $n^{\rm th}$ root of 1, and the permutation matrix corresponding to a cycle of length $n$. The inverse image of this subgroup in $\mathrm{GL}_n$ is not commutative, while the inverse image of a maximal torus in $\mathrm{PGL}_n$ is a maximal torus in $\mathrm{GL}_n$, so $G$ is not contained in a torus.

Answer (score 9):

To reinforce Angelo's example, it's worthwhile to point out the broader setting for this kind of question: the study of centralizers and connectedness properties in a semisimple (or more generally reductive) algebraic group.   An older but very useful source is part II of the extensive notes by T.A. Springer and R. Steinberg on conjugacy classes, part of an IAS seminar (Lect. Notes in Math. 131, Springer, 1970).    A crucial question is whether a given connected semisimple group is *simply connected* or not; this shows up in the standard example where the adjoint group $\mathrm{PGL}$ fails to be simply connected.   Here you have the deep theorem: If $G$ is a connected, simply connected algebraic group over an algebraically closed field, then all centralizers of semisimple elements are connected.    (It's elementary on the other hand to prove that all centralizers in a general linear group are connected.)   The role of the characteristic of the field is also discussed in depth by Springer and Steinberg, as well as the role of "torsion primes" (treated more fully in Steinberg, *Torsion in reductive groups*, Advances in Math 1975).

Some of the results are written up in later textbooks and in the first two chapters of my 1990 AMS book *Conjugacy Classes in Semisimple Algebraic Groups* (with the relevant example for the question here given in 1.12).

ADDED: To answer the added question, in any connected algebraic group it's true that an arbitrary semisimple element and hence the cyclic subgroup it generates lies in some maximal torus.    This is part of the standard development of Borel-Chevalley structure theory (see for example  Section 22.3 of my book *Linear Algebraic Groups*), though it does take a while to get that far into the theory.

Comment: The connectedness theorem you quote shows that if G is simply connected and $D$ is a smooth diagonalizable subgroup scheme, it is contained in a maximal torus. I believe it is still true for any -- possibly non-reduced -- diagonalizable subgroup scheme $D$ that the centralizer of $D$ in $G$ is connected when $G$ is simply connected; I'm unaware of an existing reference, though. (In fact, I have some notes on related matters that are waiting to be written up carefully...)

Comment: @George McNinch: Could you please explain, HOW the connectedness theorem quoted by Jim Humphreys shows that if $G$ is simply connected and $D$ is a smooth diagonalizable subgroup scheme, then $D$ is contained in a maximal torus.

Comment: Sorry - my argument in support of that remark wasn't correct. 

Comment: @George Also the assertion of your remark is not correct, see Jim's answer to my question
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60945


Comment: @Mikhail: I suspected as much. In fact, yesterday I tried to write down an example. But yesterday was busy and I made a hash of it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another example similar to Angelo's construction of a non-toral diagonalizable subgroup of a reductive group. I'll suppose that the characteristic is not 2.
Let $G = SO(V) = SO(V,\beta)$ for $\dim V > 2$, and write $V$ as an orthogonal sum
$V = U \perp W$ for $0 < \dim U < \dim V$ with $\dim U$ *even*,
such that the restriction of $\beta$ to $U$ and $W$ is non-degenerate.

Let $t \in G$ act as the identity on $W$ and as $-1$ on $U$. Then the 
centralizer $M=C_G(t)$ identifies with the subgroup 
{$(x,y) \in O(U) \times O(W) \mid \det(x) = \det(y)$}. In particular,
this centralizer is not connected: $M/M^0$ has order 2.

One can evidently choose an involution $s \in M \setminus M^0$, and then
$D = \langle t,s\rangle$ is a diag. subgroup of $G$ which is contained
in no maximal torus.

Part of this construction can be made in char. 2. Instead of $t$, you have
to take a non-smooth subgroup $\mu \simeq \mu_2$, essentially given by
the action of a semisimple element $X \in \operatorname{Lie}(G)$ ($X$ should
act as $1$ on $U$ and $0$ on $W$). Then $M=C_G(\mu) = C_G(X)$ is again
disconnected (well, now you can't argue by determinants) with component
group of order $2$. But this doesn't seem to lead to a non-toral diagonalizable
subgroup (any finite order element representating the non-trivial
coset of $M/M^0$ has a non-trivial unipotent part).